# I'm using Inotify to track changes and git add

Tags: git, centos, inotify

I'm using Inotify to track changes to a specific folder and it's subfolders (with a command to scan each subdir).

What I need to do is run a git-add into the repo, but when I do this it triggers another inotify event, and my server get into this loop. There is another way to see if there are any changes in the folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried excluding '.git' and subfolders from the inotify list?

Comment: If that isn't the problem, consider restricting the inotify mask to exclude the "IN_OPEN" and "IN_ACCESS" mask.  You should only be interested in Create/Modify/Delete operations.